# Requests why does this fail when is get a secure link

Tags: python, http, python-requests

When I try to make a secure request I get a strange error and i cant find the bug. Im sure it's somthing stupid.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


'''
this module was designed with web scrapers and web crawlers in mind.
I find my self writing these functions all the time. I Wrote this model
to save time.
'''

import requests
import urlparse
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
import os
import json
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

class InvalidURL(Exception):
    pass

class URL(object):
    '''Common routines for dealing with URLS.
    '''
    def __init__(self, url):
        '''Setup the initial state
        '''
        self.raw_url = url
        self.url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
        self.scheme = self.url.scheme
        self.domain = self.url.netloc
        self.path = self.url.path
        self.params = self.url.params
        self.query = self.url.query
        self.fragment = self.url.fragment


    def __str__(self):
        ''' This os called when somthing
        asks for a string representation of the
        url
        '''
        return self.raw_url


    def valid(self):
        """Validate the url.

        returns True if url is valid
        and False if it is not
        """
        regex = re.compile(
            r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://' # http:// or https://
            r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|'
            r'localhost|' #localhost...
            r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' # ...or ip
            r'(?::\d+)?' # optional port
            r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
        match = regex.match(self.raw_url)
        if match:
            return True


    def unquote(self):
        """unquote('abc%20def') -> 'abc def'."""

        return urllib2.unquote(self.raw_url)


    def quote(self):
        """quote('abc def') -> 'abc%20def'

        Each part of a URL, e.g. the path info, the query, etc., has a
        different set of reserved characters that must be quoted.

        RFC 2396 Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax lists
        the following reserved characters.

        reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
                      "$" | ","

        Each of these characters is reserved in some component of a URL,
        but not necessarily in all of them.

        By default, the quote function is intended for quoting the path
        section of a URL.  Thus, it will not encode '/'.  This character
        is reserved, but in typical usage the quote function is being
        called on a path where the existing slash characters are used as
        reserved characters.
        """
        return urllib2.quote(self.raw_url)


    def parameters(self):
        """
        parse the parameters of the url
        and return them as a dict.
        """
        return urlparse.parse_qs(self.params)


    def secure(self):
        """ Checks if the url uses ssl. """
        if self.scheme == 'https':
            return True


    def extention(self):
        """ return the file extention """
        return os.path.splitext(self.path)[1]


    def absolute(self):
        """ Checks if the URL is absolute. """
        return bool(self.domain)


    def relitive(self):
        """ Checks if the url is relitive. """
        return bool(self.scheme) is False


    def encode(self, mapping):
        """Encode a sequence of two-element tuples or dictionary into a URL query string.

        If any values in the query arg are sequences and doseq is true, each
        sequence element is converted to a separate parameter.

        If the query arg is a sequence of two-element tuples, the order of the
        parameters in the output will match the order of parameters in the
        input.
        """
        query = urllib.urlencode(mapping)
        return urlparse.urljoin(self.raw_url, query)


class Request(object):


    allow_redirects = True
    timeout = 5
    ramdom_useragent = 0
    verify = False
    session = requests.Session()
    stream = True
    proxies = {}

    def __init__(self, url):
        """ Set the inital state """
        self.agentHeaders = {}
        self.url = URL(url)
        if not self.url.valid():
            raise InvalidURL("{} is invalid".format(url))

    def stream(self, answer):
        self.stream = bool(answer)

    def randomUserAgent(self):
        """ Set a random User-Agent """
        self.setUserAgent(UserAgent().random)


    def allowRedirects(self, answer):
        """ Choose whether or not to follow redirects."""
        self.allow_redirects = bool(answer)


    def setUserAgent(self, agent):
        """ Set the User-Agent """
        self.setHeaders('User-Agent', agent)


    def setHeaders(self, key, value):
        """ Set custom headers """
        self.agentHeaders[key] = value


    def verify(self, answer):
        """ Set whether or not to verify SSL certs"""
        self.verify = bool(answer)


    def get(self):
        """Sends a GET request"""
        return self.session.get(
            url=self.url,
            headers=self.agentHeaders,
            allow_redirects=self.allow_redirects,
            timeout=self.timeout,
            verify=self.verify,
            stream=self.stream,
            proxies=self.proxies
            )


    def head(self):
        """ Send a head request and return the headers """
        return self.session.head(
            self.url,
            headers=self.agentHeaders,
            allow_redirects=self.allow_redirects,
            timeout=self.timeout,
            verify=self.verify,
            proxies=self.proxies
            ).headers


    def options(self):
        """ Send a options request and return the options """
        return self.session.options(
            self.url,
            headers=self.agentHeaders,
            allow_redirects=self.allow_redirects,
            timeout=self.timeout,
            verify=self.verify,
            proxies=self.proxies
            ).headers['allow']


    def json(self):
        """
        Deserialize json data (a ``str`` or ``unicode`` instance
        containing a JSON document) to a Python object.
        """
        return json.loads(self.text)


    def headerValue(self, value):
        """ Get a value from the headers. """
        return self.headers().get(value)



request = Request('https://www.google.com')
req =  request.get()
print req.text
print request.head()
print 
print req.headers.get('link')
print request.options()

request = Request('https://www.google.com')
req =  request.get()

Sat Jul 29 HttpClient python UserAgent.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UserAgent.py", line 234, in <module>
    req =  request.get()
  File "UserAgent.py", line 192, in get
    proxies=self.proxies
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 515, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 224, in cert_verify
    if not cert_loc or not os.path.exists(cert_loc):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 26, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instancemethod found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `Request.verify` method:

```
def verify(self, answer):
    """ Set whether or not to verify SSL certs"""
    self.verify = bool(answer)
```

it clashes with `Request.verify` attribute.

So, when you call your `Request.get()`, you're passing your `verify` instance method to `verify` parameter in `requests.session.get(..., verify=<your method>)`, instead of string (which [should point to a certificate bundle](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)) or `bool`.

The clue was in your stack trace: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instancemethod found`.

Solution: rename your `verify` method to something like `setVerify` (to be consistent with other methods).

Unrelated to this issue, I would suggest you implement your `Request` class by extending the `requests.Session` class. That way you'll have much less methods to define (like `get`, `head`, `json`, etc.)